# Hibernate HQL to Criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to translate a simple HQL to Criteria API, can anyone help me?
This is my HQL:

```
SELECT ch FROM Parent p JOIN p.childeren ch WHERE p.id = :id
```

As a result I get children. Important thing is there there is no relation from Child to Parent.
There is only relation in Parent to children like this:

```java
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
private List children;
```

How can I get the same results using criteria-api?

Comment: no relation from Child to Parent?  Show us your mappings, please.

Comment: Original problem is not about children and parents. I have changed it to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only fetching an associated entity is a huge pain using the Criteria API. You would need sub-queries:

```
    DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Parent.class);
    subCriteria.createCriteria("children", "c");
    subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("c.id"));
    subCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", 1));
    // Assuming Children is the name of the class
    Criteria criteria = sess.createCriteria(Children.class);
    criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("id", subCriteria));
    criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this problem is to use **sqlRestriction**, as in example below, but this is not nice because it requires to use database column name.

`Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Child.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.parent_id = ?", parentId, LongType.INSTANCE));`

*Does someone have a better solution?*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a query for this, because you can do:

```
Set<Child> children = session.get(Parent.class, id).getChildren();
children.size(); // trigger lazy initialization
```

Comment: The question was "How to translate the HQL to Criteria-API?" Your solution is not Criteria API.